Right shift operator ( >> ) can change number sign
We can read about Right shift operator >> on MDN

... the sign of the resulting number is the same as the sign of the first operand.

However, 3332508426 >> 24 === -58 in my Chrome 127.0.6533.120.
How that could be explained?
By the way, 3332508426 is decimal representation of IP 198.162.11.10.

explained what ? the integer conversion to IP address ?

No, i don't understand why 3332508426 >> 24 === -58 (why >> operator changed number sign)

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Right_shift#description

The >> operator is overloaded for two types of operands: number and BigInt. For numbers, the operator returns a 32-bit integer.

As 3332508426 is already a 32-bit integer, it uses that value.  However, 32-bit numbers are signed and the 32-bit binary representation of your number's left-most bit is a 1, so is a negative value.

     9 (base 10): 00000000000000000000000000001001 (base 2)
    -9 (base 10): 11111111111111111111111111110111 (base 2)

One solution is to convert your number to BigInt first, then convert back, ie:


let result = Number(BigInt(3332508426) >> BigInt(24));

console.log(result);
console.log(Number((BigInt(3332508426) >> BigInt(16)) % BigInt(1<<8)))
console.log(Number((BigInt(3332508426) >> BigInt(8)) % BigInt(1<<8)))
console.log(Number(BigInt(3332508426) % BigInt(1<<8)))




the fist reason is because you are using a sign-propagating right shift (>>) operator doc
The second reason is that your number, in 32-bit binary representation (which is the standard in JavaScript) ends up with a 1 in MSb 0 duly taken into account as sign bit by the operator >>
(if it is set to 1, this indicate a negative value, and the >> operator repeat this value)
to avoid this problem simply use an Unsigned right shift (>>>) operator doc
then 3332508426 >>> 24 === 198
PS: Unsigned right shift does not accept BigInt values.
sample usage:


const n2ip = n => [24,16,8,0].map(shift => n >>> shift & 0xFF).join('.');
 
console.log( n2ip(3332508426) ); // 198.162.11.10


//PS: with signed right shift you can also use :
console.log(  3332508426 >> 24 & 0xFF ); // 198




"which is the standard" - it's only the "standard" when used with >> (or other operators such as >>>) - from your link: integer[s] with more than 32 bits will be converted to a 32-bit integer

To be clear: +1 for reference to >>> which is the simplest solution for OP.

@fdomn-m To be honest, I had already upvoted yours :). But after my answer, I realized that using the mask 0xFF also solved his problem (3332508426 >> 24 & 0xFF === 198) with the advantage of working for BigInt (and therefore for IPV6)

Others have explained why it's negative, but if your just after extracting the bytes from a Uint32,..
Another option, instead of bit shifting, if you want to extract the bytes from a Uint32, in a particular endianness, create a Dataview into a Uint8Array and use the setUint32 method.  You can then read the bytes for the IP address.
eg.


let a = new Uint8Array(4); 
new DataView(a.buffer).setUint32(0, 3332508426)
console.log([...a].join('.'));




Note that the endianness of this is dependent on the environment. See also DataView.

@Ry-  Good catch!, but you might struggle to find a JS runtime that's not little endian these days.  For some reason had it in my mind it was fixed endianness, but that was likely the Dataview as you pointed out.  Updated to use Dataview, as you never know what CPU's are for the future.. :)

Javascript bit manipulation works with 32-bit signed integers.
1<<31 for example gives -2147483648
Numeric values however use floating point double precision (64 bit IEEE754), so there is no problem in writing for example
x = 2147483648
and if you display x you get 2147483648 (integers are represented without loss of accuracy up to ∓2⁵³ = ∓9007199254740992 ... much more than 32 bit).
For example however just shifting x by ZERO places you get -2147483648
x << 0 returns -2147483648
because the computation is done using 32-bit signed integers.

3332508426 is HEX C6A20B0A.
If that is interpreted as 32 bit integer, the MSB is 1 so it is negative.
Right shifting keeps the sign.

I don't understand why you wrote what the HEX representation of my number is.

@Borneo777  I wondered that, the only thing I can think is that C in binary is 1100 and the left most bit then is 1, and maybe he's old school and has the HEX to BIN parrot fashioned.  Of course this only works for big endian (what Javascript uses), for little endian you would need to pick the second to last Hex char, and then the first left bit of the quad bit.  It's kind of what made HEX popular in old Assembler etc, HEX to BIN was easier than DEC to BIN etc. IOW: if the first 0 padded HEX value is 8-F is a negative number.

Right so, Keith. The C has the MSB = 1, probably not everyone understands that immediately (that is not meant as an insult btw). It's my hardware background ;-)

@LexW. thank you for your explanation
